# How to fix incorrect position of "bars button" on mobile version?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, version, smartphone

i have one little problem that dont can resolve myself, so need some tip. On mobile version on my [dev site](http://babybolido.com/), bars in button are moved to bottom a little so looks very bad.

[image]

How to fix that? i found that CSS class in that button is:

```
#header .nav-toggle a mark
```

but dont see parameter for handle position. Any tip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the font-size of:

```
#header .nav-toggle a{}
```

Comment: How you meen? i dont see font-size in CSS class.

Comment: If you add #header .nav-toggle a{font-size:20px;} to your CSS it should fix this issue.